# How to solve differential equations in just in reals?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I am working on a variation problem:

My goal is to find the curve that connects a point $(x_1, y_1)$ to another point $(x_2, y_2)$. When this curve is revolved around the x-axis, it should generate a surface with the smallest possible surface area.

To achieve this, I need to employ the calculus of variations, specifically focusing on the following functional:

$$I = 2\pi \int_{a}^{b} |y| \sqrt{1 + (y')^2} dx$$

The Euler-Lagrange Equation for this problem is given by:

$$yy'' - (y')^2 - 1 = 0$$

I used the Wolfram engine to solve this problem, and the result I obtained is displayed below:

[image]

It's evident that this problem is entirely within the realm of real numbers, and I do not wish to obtain results that include complex numbers. However, I'm uncertain about the method to achieve this.

In the past, I attempted to set $\mathrm{e}^{C_1}C_2 = \frac{\mathrm{i}\pi}{2} + D$, and this approach yielded the real number solution because $\tanh\left(x + \frac{\mathrm{i}\pi}{2}\right) = \coth(x)$. However, I've realized that this method is not always straightforward.

Comment: In 13.3.1 on Windows 10 `DSolve[y[x]*y''[x] - y'[x]^2 - y'[x] == 0, y[x], x]` produces `{{y[x] -> (1 + E^(x C[1] + C[1] C[2]))/C[1]}}`, not that you claim.

Comment: I am sorry there is a typing error. I've just fixed it.

Comment: Can you elaborate "It seems that the problem is unrelated to complex numbers, even though the results appear non-real. This is due to the fact that tanh(x)<1 for all real numbers x. My objective is to find a completely real solution. However, I'm uncertain about the method to achieve this"? TIA.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker, and my English is not very good. The problem should be with the use of "real" as I used it to represent real numbers, but it's an entirely different adjective. I've made some adjustments, do you think the current wording is appropriate?

Comment: Thank you very much for patiently pointing out my issues. @user64494

Comment: Maple 2023 answers $$y\! \left(x\right)=\frac{c_{1} \left(\frac{1}{\left({\mathrm e}^{\frac{c_{2}}{c_{1}}}\right)^{2} \left({\mathrm e}^{\frac{x}{c_{1}}}\right)^{2}}+1\right) {\mathrm e}^{\frac{c_{2}}{c_{1}}} {\mathrm e}^{\frac{x}{c_{1}}}}{2},y\! \left(x\right)=\frac{c_{1} \left(\left({\mathrm e}^{\frac{c_{2}}{c_{1}}}\right)^{2} \left({\mathrm e}^{\frac{x}{c_{1}}}\right)^{2}+1\right)}{2 {\mathrm e}^{\frac{c_{2}}{c_{1}}} {\mathrm e}^{\frac{x}{c_{1}}}}$$

Comment: Thank you a lot.